# How to remove dust from fridge coils?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen, appliances, dust

My Whirlpool side by side fridge has the external coils underneath the fridge, with a fan to circulate air. Over the years the coils collect a lot of dust. For some reason the coils are sort of M shaped, so I can only reach the front part with the vacuum cleaner. How can I remove the dust from the rest of the coils? I don't have a compressor, so I can't use compressed air to blow the dust off. [image: You can see the front coil, and the collected dust behind it.]

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a hair blow dryer? That would definitely help.  An inexpensive can of compressed air could work too.  (Both of those would be extremely messy; it might help to be running one or more household vacuums around the refrigerator at the same time.)

I suspect you could also get a feather duster wand.  (A specific brand comes to mind, but it's not polite to mention brands on this forum!)

Answer (score 2):

After doing a search for ["whirlpool side by side refrigerator clean coils"](//google.com/search?q=whirlpool+side+by+side+refrigerator+clean+coils) there are some videoes suggesting variations over this procedure:

- Empty out the refrigerator to make it easier to handle, and disconnect it from the main supply
- Get another person to tilt the refrigerator, so that the bottom is easier available (Do not tip it over, but just tilt it enough for you to get access under it)
- Use your choice of cleaner to clean out the coils. Some cleaners which are available:

  - Vacuum cleaner (with or without the possiblity to reverse the air flow)
  - Damp, soft cloths
  - [Refrigerator coil brush](//google.com/search?q=refrigerator+coil+brush) or other sorts of suitable brushes
- Reset the refrigerator, fill it and turn it back on again

Answer (score 1):

If you fit your vacuum cleaner with it's narrow nozzle and tape two or three drinks straws securely into this you can then use the vacuum cleaner on a relatively low setting to get right in between the fridge coils with the end of the drinks straws which are now effectively the end of your vacuum cleaner.

I wouldn't advise doing this if you can't reduce your vacuum cleaner to a low power as of full power you risk overheating and damaging the vacuum cleaner with prolonged use.

Answer (score 0):

A leaf blower is the ideal tool to clean off otherwise inaccessible coils.
Pull out fridge remove back access panel, tape a fitted sheet or similar over the back to catch the dust and let rip with a leaf blower in the front.

Comment: Hi brent, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE. We hope you enjoy your time here. Please visit the Help Centre (? menu icon) above for information about how better to use this site.

Comment: You DO realize this refrigerator is inside?

Comment: I do mine with a leaf blower.  But I do roll it to the door first.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a spare wire coat hanger handy, you could straighten it out into a long thin pole and wrap some cloth around it tightly (enough for it not to fall off, but not too much so that it doesn't fit in the gaps).

Then use this to like a cloth on a stick to get in between the coils and also to clean behind them.

Comment: To whom downvoted my answer - could you at least explain why? I see no issues with it and actually do this for more than just the OP's situation.